# url re-write php pages not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have a web address like https://www.bookspk.site/category/cat.php?caturl=islamic-literature&Page=2
I am able to redirect https://www.bookspk.site/category/cat.php?caturl=islamic-literature to https://www.bookspk.site/category/islamic-literature
by

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ cat.php?caturl=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ cat.php?caturl=$1
```

but unable to convert http://e.bookspk.net/category/cat.php?caturl=islamic-books&Page=2 to http://e.bookspk.net/category/islamic-books/2
used this code

```
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$    cat.php?caturl=$1&page=$2
```

worked to load the page but shows the contents of first page on all pages please help

Comment: Is your htaccess in `/category/` directory? Can you show full .htaccess in question?

Comment: yes my .tacces file in category directory and complete file is                      RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$    cat.php?caturl=$1&page=$2 

RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$    cat.php?caturl=$1&page=$2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /category/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ cat.php?caturl=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ cat.php?caturl=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: worked to load http://e.bookspk.net/category/islamic-books/2 but showing first page contents on every page

Comment: I don't know code inside `cat.php` but you can use `print_r($_GET); exit;` on top of your `cat.php` to see what GET parameters are being received there.

Comment: i did and the result:                                                   Array ( [caturl] => urdu-digests [page] => 2 )

Comment: that means rules worked since you got `page=2` correctly. You just need to fix `cat.php` to show right page using `$_GET['page']`

Comment: i am using $_GET['page'] and when load page http://e.bookspk.net/category/cat.php?caturl=islamic-books&Page=2 it shows correct values

Comment: As you noted earlier even with `http://e.bookspk.net/category/islamic-books/2` it is working fine since your are getting `Array ( [caturl] => urdu-digests [page] => 2 )` showing you `$_GET['page']` is `2`

Comment: ok brother this code is fine my php script was not getting page thanks very much its ok now